# Quais são as situações em que podemos usar "mesmo" como pronome?

Tags: pronomes, concordância-nominal

Vi numa gramática (Almeida, 2009) que não devemos usar "mesmo" no lugar de pronomes pessoais retos ou oblíquos. Um erro que é muito comum.

Assim as frases a seguir estão incorretas:

> João faz cursinho. O mesmo pretende estudar engenharia.
>   Comprei um carro. O mesmo é automático.

O correto seria:

> João faz cursinho. Ele pretende estudar engenharia.
>   Comprei um carro. Ele é automático.

No [dicionário Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mesmo) existe a seguinte definição de "mesmo" como pronome demostrativo:

> **Pronome demonstrativo**
>   2. Coisa ou pessoa que já foi mencionada anteriormente (ex.: eu fiz a tarefa, mas a mesma não ficou perfeita).

Essa frase não seria: eu fiz a tarefa, mas ela não ficou perfeita?

Quais são as situação em que podemos usar "mesmo" como pronome?

**Referências** 
ALMEIDA, Nilson Teixeira de. Gramática da Língua Portuguesa. 9 ed. São Paulo: Saraiva, 2009.

"mesmo", in [Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mesmo) [em linha], 2008-2013,  [consultado em 24-02-2016].

Comment: "Não devemos usar" e "erro" pode ser dito de uma frase que quebra as regras da gramática, mas também pode ser dito de uma frase gramatical quando há melhores alternativas. Não tenho o livro; ele diz que não é gramatical? ou diz que não é aconselhável?

Comment: A palavra mesmo quando significa algo mencionado anteriormente se usa em contextos formais. Não na linguagem cotidiana. Então, as duas primeras frases não estão "erradas" mas ninguem fala assim. Se ve em textos formais e jurídico, por exemplo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As situações em que o uso é consensual são as do [significado 1. do Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mesmo), como em *ele não é mais o mesmo*:

> 1. Indica igualdade, semelhança ou identidade (ex.: *ele vestiu estas mesmas calças ontem*; *ela continua **a mesma** apesar de tudo o que lhe aconteceu*).

O uso anafórico (o significado 2. do Priberam) é de facto criticado por várias autoridades. [Esta página](https://www.portalentretextos.com.br/index.php/post/o-mesmo-a-mesma) reúne a opinião de vários autores.

Não obstante, o uso está largamente difundido, quer no Brasil, quer em Portugal (mas, pelo menos em Portugal, somente na escrita). Também não consegui encontrar argumentos fortes contra este uso. É portanto mais uma questão de estilo.

[O Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-pronome-demonstrativo-o-mesmo/17024) nota ainda que *o mesmo* pode não ser equivalente a *ele*/*este*/etc., porque *o mesmo* tem mais tendência para ser lido como referindo-se ao elemento mais próximo. Repare-se no exemplo lá dado:

> Muitos elogiavam as suas atitudes gentis, mas eu fui traído pelas mentiras dela, nunca me dei conta ***delas***/***das mesmas***.