# É correto usar "da mesma" como termo anafórico?

Tags: gramática

Hoje, pela manhã, estive revisando alguns artigos acadêmicos e, ao remover um asterisco que faz ligação aos autores no rodapé, me deparei com a seguinte mensagem do Word:

[image]

Partindo do pressuposto de que o termo anafórico retoma um termo anterior, total ou parcialmente, de modo que, para compreendê-lo dependemos do termo antecedente, é correto usar "da mesma" (como explicitado na captura de tela supracitada) como pronome?

Comment: Bechara diz ser correto: “Alguns estudiosos, por mera escolha pessoal, têm-se insurgido contra o emprego anafórico do demonstrativo *mesmo*, substantivado pelo artigo, precedido ou não de preposição, para referir-se a palavra ou declaração expressa anteriormente. Não apresentam, entretanto, as razões da crítica”. Também recomendo ler https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/771.

Comment: Creio que já tens resposta a esta pergunta em: [Quais são as situações em que podemos usar "mesmo" como pronome?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-situa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-em-que-podemos-usar-mesmo-como-pronome)

Answer (score -2):

Se não for errado usar *o mesmo*, pelo menos esta expressão deve ser evitada. Ver [aqui][1]. O emprego de *o mesmo* é motivo de troça, especialmente o infame texto *Antes de entrar no elevador, verifique se o mesmo está parado no andar*. Ver [aqui][2]. A brincadeira é verificar se o elevador é o mesmo ou agora é outro. :-)

Tenho a impressão de que esta expressão é mais comum entre os paulistas, mas não conheço nenhuma pesquisa que se debruce sobre este ponto. Deve-se usar, em vez de *o mesmo* ou *a mesma*, o pronome pessoal *ele* ou *ela*. Parece-me que o erro é cometido por pessoas que querem soar mais eruditos sem o ser, e acham que *ele* ou *ela* é simples demais para quem quer *falar difícil*.

[1]: https://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/portugues/mesmo-voce-sabe-utilizar-o-pronome.htm#:~:text=Diz%20a%20gram%C3%A1tica%20que%20n%C3%A3o,%22mesmo%22%20como%20pronome%20pessoal.&text=A%20forma%20correta%20%C3%A9%20bastante,%22ele%22%20(...
[2]: https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/artigo.php?indice=12

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site, OraPois. Até onde sei, não é errado (Bechara), mas não é bem visto por muita gente, porém, não é errado. Na minha opinião, é melhor usar “esse” ou “ele(a)”; ex.: “Antes de abrir o elevador, verifique se ele está parado no andar” e “a vida da Maria é boa. Essa vida vai longe”, contudo, não é errado.